# Contact form Laravel 4

Tags: forms, laravel, laravel-4, contacts

Im a noob with Laravel 4 and the contact form things is giving me some trouble to make it work.
Found few things, all using controllers but I just need it in the route.

How to do the route for a simple contact form (name,email and message) to send the datas to an admin email box?

Cheers

Comment: Why not keep it in a controller, it's better IMO.

Comment: Specify the problem, please

Answer (score 15):

Here's a quick and dirty way to send e-mails using just your routes:

Create your routes

```php
Route::get('contact', function() {

    return View::make('contact');

});

Route::post('contact', function() {

    $fromEmail = Input::get('email');
    $fromName = Input::get('name');
    $subject = Input::get('subject');
    $data = Input::get('message');

    $toEmail = 'manager@company.com';
    $toName = 'Company Manager';

    Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function($message) use ($toEmail, $toName, $fromEmail, $fromName, $subject)
    {
        $message->to($toEmail, $toName)

        $message->from($fromEmail, $fromName);

        $message->subject($subject);
    });

});
```

Create a `app/views/contact.php`

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="/contact" method="POST">

            Your form

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Create `app/views/emails/contact.php`

```
<html>
    <body>
        Message: {{$data}}
    </body>
</html>
```

And you need to configure

```
app/config/mail.php
```