# Laravel mail failed to send mail

Tags: php, email, laravel, swiftmailer

So for the first time I tried `Laravel` mailer but I encountered some problems vs the normal php `mail()` which just sends the mail.

My laravel code:

```
if(Mail::send('pages/mail', $data, function($message)
{
    $message->from('webmaster@example.com', Input::get('name'));

    $message->to('nobody@example.com')->subject('Welcome to My Laravel app!');
}))
{
    return "success";
}
else
{
    return Mail::failures();
}
```

My laravel error response:

```
"["nobody@example.com"]"
```

(basically the mail address I put in `to()`.

If I use the normal php `mail()` it sends the mail without error (it only came into my spam folder but it was just a test).

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Shouldn't your view be `pages.mail`?

Comment: @hebron Thanks for your reply, it functions just as well but you're right, Laravel's conventions are using dots

Comment: I used this post as a guide for my mail contact form, http://stackoverflow.com/a/20397133/3903565 and that works.

Comment: @hebron I tried it, but receive the same error.

Comment: Hm, that works for me. Are you sure you have set the correct driver in the mail config?

Comment: @hebron Thanks, that was it, I used the wrong driver, so stupid of me! thanks again!

Comment: I'll post this as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you are using the correct mail driver in `config/mail.php`:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mail Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
| sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
| your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
|
| Supported: "smtp", "mail", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "log"
|
*/

'driver' => 'mail',
```